# Override Docker Folders with Volumes

Tags: docker

I'm in need of certain local folders acting like *overrides*, for lack of a better explanation.
I want to tell my docker container `/this/local/folder:/this/docker/folder` has files in it that I want to override in `/this/docker/folder` but please do use all the other files `/this/docker/folder` has that the container image provides. Right now with the knowledge I have of docker, is i specify `/this/local/folder:/this/docker/folder`, the container goes *replace my /this/docker/folder in the container with that one, and if it's empty on local, it will be empty in here*.
Any way to do what I'm needing?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. What might work is mounting the volume on `/a` and having the image files in `/b`. Then have a startup script that copies the volume files from `/a` to `/b`.

Comment: I thought of doing that, but thought maybe there was a better, less hack-like way to go about it.